# How to make an USB cable cross a door?

Tags: usb, connector, cables, usb-c, ribbon-cable

<sup>*Note: I am torn between posting this here, SE DIY or SE IoT. Since this is related to powering on my smart devices and the electrical connection I need to use, I finally settled down on SE EE. Please let me know if this is out of scope and I will move it somewhere else*</sup>

I have a Nuki Smart Lock and I want to do exactly what the manual says not to do:

[image]

I would like the USB cable to cross the frame of the door by using a "connector" - a device that would have a set of bare metal endings on both side that can touch and provide a closed circuit, and be disconnected when the door is open. The connector on the Nuki is a USB-C.

My main problem is that I do not know how such device is called in English (now that I think of it I could also post at *SE English Learners* :)).

Is there a standard way for a USB-C cable to be split that way?

Comment: Why not have a longer cable cross the door frame over its top and then come in from the left as intended?

Comment: Even if such a thing that allows sliding contacts to pass/slide from door frame to door when closed, surely it will exist outside the scope of it being an USB connection. You simply seem to want 5V power, not USB?

Comment: @Justme: yes, I need power, but I think that USB also provides intelligent signaling and the Nuki may negotiate something with the charger. If this is not the case then yes, it is simply a matter of 5V and a USB plug on the device side

Comment: @user107063 for two main reasons: the first one is that the cable will need to be glued/attached somehow to the frame and it will not be particularly aesthetical (I have a Chief Home Officer to appraise), and then this cable will be constantly under stress when the door open /closes (even if I allow a loose loop). These may not be very good reasons but I wanted to explore the gapped connection anyway. My door is placed in such a way that the cable would need to go up, right, up (that parts is the loose one as it connects the door and the wall), left, down and left. Quite a ride.

Comment: @WoJ If it simply wants 5V from charger and it's standard USB (not Type-C) it cannot and will not communicate anything with the charger.

Comment: @Justme: it is USB-C connector (but I do not know if this is just the form factor, or if there is some intelligence as well)

Comment: @WoJ then it depends - USB-C interfaces must not give out supply voltage unless negotiated, only exception is adapters to legacy connectos that can't work in any other way than providing 5V all the time. That info that it's Type-C is important and you should add that to your question. And any custom connector in a USB connection will easily break the safe hotpluggability and incorrect hotplugging sequence of wires may cause damage. Which is why nobody should buy/use/manufacture those magnetic Type-C adapters as they are unsafe too.

Comment: @Justme Thank you. I updated the post. With this information in hand, I belive that the right thing to do will be to route a long USB-C cable around the frame of the door (despite bing a long way, per an earlier comment)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simular thing with my door and I used thin enamelled copper wires sandwiched between two adhesive tapes (the isolating ones).

One thing to watch out for: These copper wires have isolation varnish which could lead you into thinking that you can stick them on bare metal. But as this varnish has a lot of small defects, you will get shorts. So you need isolation on bare metal door frames. I learned this the hard way.